# Extracting multiple nested .tar files

Tags: command-line, tar

I have 3 `tar` files of huge size (~100 GB, each), and each of them have multiple `tar` files inside them, which contain images. Is it possible to unpack all of them in their respective hierarchy? For example, if my 3 large `tar` files are `a.tar`, `b.tar`, and `c.tar`, and each of them contain `1.tar`, `2.tar`, and so on, after extraction, I want the images to be in their respective paths, like `a/2/img37.jpg`, or `c/1/img346.jpg`, and so on. Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help you

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nested.tar.archives.extractor/1.1

1.Ensure you have either python 2.6 or python 2.7 installed.

2.Extract the downloaded file "nested.tar.archives.extractor-1.1 [python 2.x].tar.gz"

3.Copy the file "extractnested.py" to one of the folders in your PATH environment variable
    (Note: For linux users, as you might know, to allow execution of extractnested.py as a bash script, you need to grant it permissions - $ chmod ugo+rx extractnested.py)

Now you can extract any tar archive from the terminal -

```
extractnested.py path [path ...]
```

where path is the path of the tar archive you want to extract.

Comment: Hope it works :)

Comment: So, if my paths are `./a.tar`, `./b.tar`, and so on, I just use the command as `$ extractnested.py ./a.tar [./a.tar ...]`, right? Also, will `$ extractnested.py ./*.tar [./*.tar ...]` work, for extracting all the `tar` files at once?

Comment: I have checked and it works perfectly :)

Comment: I used this in my terminal: `$ extractnested.py ILSVRC2012_img_train.tar [ILSVRC2012_img_train.tar ...]`, and this is the error message showing up: `zsh: bad pattern: [ILSVRC2012_img_train.tar`

Comment: You should't type that $ symbol

Comment: I dod not type the `$` symbol; just used it to represent the terminal. What does the path in the square braces `[path ...]` do? In the README file, they used path to a different tar file in the square braces: `extractnested tar1.tar [tar2.tar ...]`

Comment: Oh no! No square braces is needed

Comment: You know square braces means optional :)

Comment: It worked now. I did not know square braces mean optional!

Comment: Feeling happy :) :)